# How to trigger and listen to global events in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I know EventDispatcher is capable of firing events in between objects, but how about a global event where any object in the hierarchy can listen and respond to? Is there a recommended way of doing this properly in EaselJS, and is it a good idea in general?

Answer (score 2):

Events can go through any object and any object can listen to any event, you just have to initialize EaselJS events for your custom objects through:

```
EventDispatcher.initialize(myObject);
```

If you want it to be globally accessible I think you'd have to use something like `window.myGlobalEventHub` as the dispatching object, or some other window-variable that can be accessed from anywhere.